# Xamarin Forms - Image To/From IRandomAccessStreamReference

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, bing-maps, marker, uwp-maps

For personal needs, for the **Xamarin.Forms.Map** control, I need to create a `CustomPin` extension. *UWP part (PCL project)*

I create a `MapIcon` like it:

```
nativeMap.MapElements.Add(new MapIcon()
{
    Title = pin.Name,
    Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Pin/customicon.png")),
    Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = pin.Position.Latitude, Longitude = pin.Position.Longitude }),
    NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Windows.Foundation.Point(0.5, 1.0)
});
```

However, by this way, I can't set the `Image`'s size.

I then want to use an `Image` from my PCL part, resize it and convert it into a `IRandomAccessStreamReference`. To realize it, I need to convert my `Image` into a stream, but I can't find the way to make it works ><

Example of the function needed:

```
private IRandomAccessStreamReference ImageToIRandomAccessStreamReference(Image image)
{
    //Here I can set the size of my Image

    //I convert it into a stream
    IRandomAccessStreamReference irasr = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(/* img? */);

    //irasr is then created from img

    //I return the IRandomAccessStreamReference needed by the MapIcon element
    return irasr;
}
```

**Note:** The `Image` paramter *img* is a **Xamarin.Forms.Image**

**So first, is it possible? If yes, then thank for any help which could help me.. I already search about how to resize the MapIcon and it's not possible directly from the class [MapIcon].(https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapicon.aspx)**

Thank for help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right. We can't resize the [MapIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapicon.aspx) directly as it doesn't provide such properties or methods. MapIcon's size is mostly controlled by the size of image which is set by [MapIcon.Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapicon.image.aspx) property. And we can set this image's size without using **Xamarin.Forms.Image**.

To set this image's size, we can take advantage of [**BitmapDecoder class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapdecoder.aspx), **[BitmapEncoder class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx)** and [**BitmapTransform class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.bitmaptransform.aspx) like following:

```cs
private async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<RandomAccessStreamReference> ResizeImage(StorageFile imageFile, uint scaledWidth, uint scaledHeight)
{
    using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read))
    {
        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);

        //create a RandomAccessStream as output stream
        var memStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        //creates a new BitmapEncoder and initializes it using data from an existing BitmapDecoder
        BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(memStream, decoder);

        //resize the image
        encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = scaledWidth;
        encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = scaledHeight;

        //commits and flushes all of the image data
        await encoder.FlushAsync();

        //return the output stream as RandomAccessStreamReference
        return RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(memStream);
    }
}
```

And then we can use this method to create a resized image stream reference first and then set it as `MapIcon`'s `Image` like:

```cs
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Pin/customicon.png"));
var imageReference = await ResizeImage(file, 64, 64);

nativeMap.MapElements.Add(new MapIcon()
{
    Title = pin.Name,
    Image = imageReference,
    Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = pin.Position.Latitude, Longitude = pin.Position.Longitude }),
    NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Windows.Foundation.Point(0.5, 1.0)
});
```

Comment: Hi ! Ho god, I'm searching from so long ! I'll give it a try tonight, thank ! :)

Comment: @Emixam23 Hi, any update? If my answer didn't solve your problem, please feel free to let me know.