# UWP Map Control - Resize MapIcon Images

Tags: uwp, maps, bing

How do you increase the size of MapIcons and Billboard Images?  I've tried the stylesheets scaling as well as C# code, but it does not seem to change.

```
var mapIcon = new MapIcon()
{
    Location = new Geopoint(
        new BasicGeoposition
        {
            Latitude = entry.Latitude,
            Longitude = entry.Longitude,
        }),
    NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Windows.Foundation.Point(0.5, 1.0),
    Title = entry.Name,
    Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri($"ms-appx:///Assets/KMZ/Pins/icon.png"))                
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `MapIcon` does not provide an API to resize itself, you must resize the image that is used yourself.

Resizing the image can be done using using `BitmapDecoder`, which reads the source image and `BitmapEncoder` which allows you to write a modified stream of the bitmap (even in memory). Resizing can be done using `BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth` and `BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight` APIs.

**Jay Zuo** shared a full solution in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39632398/732221). Although the question mentions Xamarin.Forms, this technique is purely UWP-based so it fully applies to your issue as well.

Comment: thanks.  I figured that would be the answer, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something before I started down that path.  Thanks for the refrences on how to pull this off.  I'll mess with it today and provide any additional comments.  Then I'll mark the answer to you.

Comment: Worked great!  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad it helped :-) !